# Can I use software serial rx on attiny84 pin 0?

Tags: arduino

Please address using ATtiny84 physical pin 13 (logical pin 0) (RESET) ("D10"?) as a software serial RX.

Comment: Is that a pin that you can read from software, according to the datasheet?

Comment: what does the datasheet say?  do you want to use the uart or reverse bit bang it yourself?

Comment: @old_timer does the Tiny84 even contain an UART?

Comment: @Justme good question.  the OP should have all the docs before starting a project or even a question like this so I guess we will find out.